# Conexão ViewModel com Repositorio

Tags: android, viewmodel

Olá, tudo bem?

Estou com um cenário que é o seguinte: no Android estou precisando conectar a minha ViewModel com o Repositório. Eu consegui fazer, porém, eu só não sei se fiz da maneira correta. Dentro do meu ViewModel eu tenho um liveData, no meu ViewModel eu faço uma chamada assíncrona com retrofit. Segui a minha implementação. Eu posso fazer isso dentro do ViewMode? Considerando a alta-coesão e baixo-acoplamento?

```
private void carregarItems() {

    mListaMutableLiveDataServico = new MutableLiveData<List<ProdutoServico>>();
    mListaMutableLiveDataProduto = new MutableLiveData<List<ProdutoServico>>();

    MainAPI mMainAPI = ConfigServico.criarServico(MainAPI.class);
    Call<List<ProdutosServicos>> mCallModelMain = mMainAPI.obterEntidadesMain();

    mAlertDialog = new ProgressBarUtils(mContext).criarAlerta();
    mAlertDialog.show();

    mCallModelMain.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProdutosServicos>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ProdutosServicos>> call, Response<List<ProdutosServicos>> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful())
                return;

            mListaMutableLiveDataProduto.setValue(response.body().get(0).getProdutos());
            mListaMutableLiveDataServico.setValue(response.body().get(1).getServicos());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ProdutosServicos>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error: ", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Vinícius!

Considerando alta-coesão e nível de acomplamento a resposta é **não**. No seu código, você delega tarefas ao `ViewModel` que são relativas ao `Repository`. Como você considera o uso de um `Repository`, deixe que ele faça o trabalho sozinho e só depois passe os dados ao `ViewModel`, deixando-o a cargo do gerenciamento da UI (`Activity`/`Fragment`) e suas requisições a esses dados. Vejamos na prática:

**MessagesRepository.class**

```
public class MessagesRepository {
    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Message>> mMessages;

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Message>> getMessages(String uid) {
        if(mMessages == null) mMessages = new MutableLiveData();

        // Faça sua chamada a base de dados aqui e use
        // o método postValue() do MutableLiveData em resultados 
        // de chamadas assíncronas

        return mMessages;
    }
}
```

**MessagesViewModel.class**

```
public class MessagesViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MessagesRepository mRepository;

    public MessagesViewModel(MessagesRepository repository) {
        mRespository = repository;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Message>> getMessages(String uid) {
        return mRepository.getMessages(uid);
    }
}
```

Perceba que agora o `Repository` é o único responsável por obter os dados, independentemente de onde estejam, pois o `ViewModel` não sabe de onde eles vêm. Eles podem vir de um armazenamento local ou de uma API, por exemplo. Desse modo, você consegue mudar sua fonte de dados a qualquer momento sem causar efeitos colaterais nos demais componentes. Isso é o que é recomendado pela documentação. Porém, o acesso aos dados pode ser feito diretamente no `ViewModel`

Seu `ViewModel` não deve tomar qualquer tipo de decisão ou fazer qualquer outra coisa além de apresentar os dados à UI, como por exemplo, tratar `ProgressBar` ou `Dialog`. Para isso, use um `Resource` para ser notificado dos estados da requisição (carregando, falha, vazio e etc.).

**EDIT 1:**

1 - Crie um `Resource` para "trafegar" os dados e os estados das chamadas ao `ViewModel`

**Resource.java**

```
public class Resource<T> {
    private State state;
    private T data;
    private String message;

    public void setData(T data) {
      this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {
       return data;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
       this.state = state;
    }

    public State getState() {
      return state;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
       this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
      return message;
    }
}
```

2 - Crie uma `enum` para representar os estados (esses são estados básicos de qualquer requisição)

**State.java**

```
public enum State {
    SUCCESSFUL,
    FAILURE,
    EMPTY
}
```

3 - Atualize o `Repository` e o `ViewModel` para trabalharem com `Resource`

**MessagesRepository.class**

```
public class MessagesRepository {
    private MutableLiveData<Resource<ArrayList<Message>>> mMessages;

    public MutableLiveData<Resource<ArrayList<Message>>> getMessages(String uid) {
        if(mMessages == null) mMessages = new MutableLiveData();

        // Seta o estado inicial e manda isso p/ ViewModel/UI
        Resource<ArrayList<Message>> resource = new Resource<>();
                                     resource.setState(State.LOADING);
        mMessages.setValue(resource);

        // Faça sua chamada a base de dados aqui e use
        // o método postValue() do MutableLiveData em resultados 
        // de chamadas assíncronas. Não esqueça de setar os estados
        // de sucesso e falha


        return mMessages;
    }
}
```

**MessagesViewModel.class**

```
public class MessagesViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MessagesRepository mRepository;

    public MessagesViewModel(MessagesRepository repository) {
        mRespository = repository;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<Resource<ArrayList<Message>>> getMessages(String uid) {
        return mRepository.getMessages(uid);
    }
}
```

4 - Agora na sua `UI` é só gerenciar os estados mostrando `loading/progress/alert` e outras coisas

**MessagesActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);

        mMessagesModel.getMessages(/* uid */)
              .observe(this, resource -> {
              if(resource.getState() == State.LOADING) {
                  // Carregando
              }
              else if (resource.getState() == State.SUCCESSFUL) {
                  // Carregado com êxito
                  ArrayList<Message> messages = resource.getData();
              }
              else if (resource.getState() == State.FAILURE) {
                  // Falha
              }
              else {
                  // Vazio
              }
        });
    }
```

Isso é o básico. Tudo pode melhorar, principalmente no desenvolvimento. Use isso como ponto de partida. Espero que ajude!

Comment: Muito legal sua resposta, já implementei o padrão sugerido e ficou bem melhor e inteligível. Agora, para obter a estado da requisição, você tem algum exemplo de como posso utilizar esse Resource? Essa parte para mim, ainda está um pouco abstrata.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta. Implementei um exemplo de utilização do `Resource`